# angular2 forms validation - what does .ng-invalid:not(form)

Tags: css, forms, angular, angular2-forms

### Question

What does the `:not(form)` part of a CSS selector for angular2 form elements?

### Context

The current version of the [Angular2 tutorial about forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) makes use of two-way data binding, change tracking and validation to add CSS classes to form elements.

Their example form looks like this
[image]

And their example code to achive the red bar looks like this

```
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
   border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I found it out myself!

the `ng-invalid` class is `<form>` elements, too.

So, `:not(form)` is added to prevent a red bar on the left side of the *whole form*.

Answer (score 0):

The `:not(form)` part of the CSS selector represents elements that do not match a `form` element. So any DOM element excluding `form` elements.